# I have a table of un-initialized pointers to custom items that I want to check if there exists something already

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hashtable

My function looks into an Vector of pointers by accessing an index decided by a hash function.

Comment: Did you measure the time taken to initialize the pointers to null and determine that it is too long? Consider an array of `unique_ptr` which are set to an empty value automatically. Pass key by const reference.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: I have not yet measured the time taken to initialize to 0, though I will consider it.  Why pass the key by const reference?

Comment: What doesn't work about what you have? As long as `hashTable` is initialized to `nullptr` for each index it should be fine.

Comment: This is for homework, and am required to use a hashTable

Comment: Why pass it by value and copy it needlessly?

Comment: uninitialized variables are default-initialized, which can mean indeterminate. And you cannot possibly test whether it is still indeterminate.

Comment: @cocarin How would i initialize to nullptr?  Would i just set the index point to nullptr?

Comment: You can loop through and set each index, or you can do it on construction. `hashTable = new int[SizeOfHashTable]();`, by including the `()` at the end, a default constructor will be called for each element, which for `int` initializes everything to zero.

Comment: The best way to fill `hashTable` will null pointers depends on its type.

Answer (score 1):

If by `array` you mean a C array, then you'll have to initialize every index to some kind of "empty/default" value.  The program has no way of distinguishing an uninitialized sequence of random bits from some value you inserted in there, and even attempting to read uninitialized data is undefined behavior.

No matter what, you'll need some sort of "bookkeeping" mechanism to tell which elements in the array are occupied.  The easiest way is to zero-initialize the array, or initialize each value in the array to some default value.  But note that if you zero-initialize the array, you'll have no way to distinguish between an "empty" slot, and a location where you inserted `nullptr`.  You may want to consider having each element be a more complex aggregate object that contains information about whether the cell is occupied/empty/whatever.  Generally, hash tables are composed of "bucket" elements which contain the actual key/value pair, as well as meta-data such as linked-lists to additional buckets for collision resolution, or if some kind of open addressing collision resolution scheme is used, some meta-data which marks the element as occupied/free/etc.

You may also want to consider using `std::unordered_map`, or some hash table implementation that grows as you insert more elements, if that becomes an option for you outside this particular homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You  have 2 ways  to initialize your  hashTable  array  to  NULL.

1. During the  declaration, like: "type"

   ```
   hashTable[size] = {NULL};
   ```

   However, this  one  doesn't work  in  Xcode.  Fortunately, there is another  way.
2. In  the constructor of your `hashTable` class, with  a  for  loop:

   ```
   for(int  i = 0 ;  i  <  hashTable.size() ;  i++)
       hashTable[i] =  NULL;
   ```

A piece of advice: try  to give different names for  your `hashTable` class and your `hashTable` array.